# Rails, SQL Where Both Columns Match for !=

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

This returns records with both conditions.

```
Vote.where('id = 1 AND type = 'Temp')
```

This actually returns records with OR/Either columns.
How do I write this so that id and type both have to match (!=)

```
Vote.where('id != 1 AND type != 'Temp')
```

Here is the direct sql

```
SELECT * FROM ridcySemantic_development.votes WHERE (id!=4 AND answer_id!=71);
```

Comment: Can you post your real exact code? The two 'not equal' conditions with `AND` should work as intended, but this can't be your real code as it is not syntactically valid. Something else may be going on with the actual code

Comment: I actually am testing the direct sql statements. I will edit.

Comment: Ok - that SQL should work exactly as intended (the standard SQL not-equal operator is `<>` though MySQL does support `!=`). Please also post a sample of the rows in the table and a sample of what you would expect the query output to be (to eliminate any miscommunications).

Comment: Record with id=5,answer_id=71 should be returned but it's not being returned. AND is actually operating as an OR and matching !=4 OR answer!=71

Comment: Please setup a sample at http://sqlfiddle.com.

Comment: Dang - it's up and down often and I can get to it right now... For example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9c3eb8/1

Comment: Solution: WHERE NOT (id=4 AND answer_id=71)

Comment: Post that solution and I will give you the answer/points.

Answer (score 0):

WHERE NOT (id=4 AND answer_id=71)